# How to set condition on UI route in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new in angular and working on UI routing. My issue is how to set condition when user route to new state. What i want is, when user submit the form it should authenticate form data through Mobile OTP popup before going to next state. In my code everything works fine till form but when user submit form, otp popup open but its get hide when its route to new state. So i think i need to put some condition when user go to next state. 
Here are my codes

//APP.JS FILE

```
.state('main.step4', {
        url: '/step2/step3/step4',
        templateUrl: 'pages/step4.html'
        }
```

//Controller.js

```
$scope.getStep2Form = function($index, selectCarList) {
            $scope.selectCar.step2Form = selectCarList;
            $scope.step2Data = $scope.selectCar;
            console.log($scope.step2Data);
        }
        $scope.getStep3Form = function(step3FormData) {
            $scope.selectCar.step3Data = step3FormData;
            console.log($scope.selectCar);

        }
        $scope.showotp=function(){
            open_modal_menu()
        }
```

//CUSTOM.js

```
function open_modal_menu() {
            $('.modal-menu').toggleClass('active-modal-menu');
            $('.modal-menu-overlay').addClass('active-overlay');
        }
```

//SERVICES.js

```
angular.module('carmobApp.services', [])

.factory('carListDataFactry', function($http) {

var carListData = [];
return {
  all: function() {
    return $http.get("scripts/content.json").then(function(response) {
      carListData = response.data;
      //console.log(teamListData);
      return carListData;
    });

  },
  get: function(selectCarId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < carListData.length; i++) {
      if (carListData[i].id === parseInt(selectCarId)) {
        //console.log(carListData[i]);
        return carListData[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

};
});
```

//HTML

```
<a ui-sref="main.step4" class="button button-green button-full button-icon submitBtn" ng-model="selectCar.step3Data" ng-click="showotp(); getStep3Form(step3FormData)" ng-disabled="selectCarform.$invalid">
    <i class="ion-arrow-right-c" style="color:#fff;"></i> PROCEED NEXT
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $location.path(""); for redirecting on any route. in js file u can use normal if and else where as in UI u can use angular directives like ngif ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf )and ngfor.

Comment: Do you have any Plunker example for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
app.run(function($transitions) {
  $transitions.onSuccess({}, (transition) => {
  console.log(transition.to())
  console.log(transition.from())
 });
})
```

and it fire when the route was changed

or if problem with rendering

In this case, with the opening popup window on-click you need to send as parameters $event. And inside function

```
$event.preventDefault()
```

it`s prevent rout changing in URL.

and on the last step add something like

```
$state.go('state name')
```

Comment: What $transitions do here can u explain lil bit

Comment: add another explanation

Comment: CAn u look at this Plunker link (https://embed.plnkr.co/siK70Rgo0ACZPTDYfJ6v/) once ...still this problem is not resolved. Hoping this might help to understand my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$transition`](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks) hooks to catch the page transition:

```
$transitions.onStart({to: 'main.step4' }, function(transition) {
    if(!user.isAuthenticated()) //if going to the last step and user is not authenticated
        return false; //abort the transition
});

}
```

When the user authenticates you can use `$state.go('main.step4')` and continue the normal behaviuor.

Usually [`$transition`](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks) is used to verify if the user has the right permissions for going to the next page, and if not redirect to a login (if not authenticated) or home page (if not authorized).

I understand that what you want to accomplish is a "login on the fly", I'm right? If that's the case you should reconsider your app flow and think of a login state which remembers where you were and knows where you want to go.

Comment: where do i put this Code ? in which file i can put and where to initialize $state.go('main.step4').

Comment: @TarunKumar you have to put the event in a `.run`, white the `$state.go` after the modal has been closed, when the authentication is finished

Comment: i have created plunker for this question(https://embed.plnkr.co/siK70Rgo0ACZPTDYfJ6v/ ) can you please look at once . i did what u said but it's not working can u just look my code once ..Pleaseeee

Comment: @TarunKumar Try [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zHDHdNFDP94juDey05aI). Change the variable `pass` in the `app.js` file between `true` and `false` to see the transition stop. You are missing _A LOT_ of key features both of Angular and UI Router. The plunker you posted was not going to work ever. You really need to understand better those technologies and start with something simplier. Do a lot of tutorials! I've left some comments in the code indicating what was wrong... Keep trying! :)

Comment: I'm Not missing anything i have updated what you need in plunker. i checked your code but i can see you are routing a page. which i can do it. I don't want login page i need popup instead login.html page. and there we need to authenticate the page.

Answer (score -1):

so, What I understand your question is you want to show custom popup when user submit a form (authenticating a mobile no.) after authentication on click (OK button) you want to route the last page, if you clicked on (Cancel Button) remain in same route.